# В laravel 10 При вводе в форму срабатывает валидатор, но не выводит текст ошибки

Tags: laravel, form, валидация

К сожалению не имею пока валидации в других частях кода для сравнения и поиска ошибки.

**Контроллер**:

```
public function createNewUser(Request $request): Response|RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate($this->getValidationRules());

    $photo = $this->handleProfilePhoto($request);
    $data = $this->prepareUserData($request, $photo);

    $user = new User();
    $user->create($data);
    $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success','Registering was successful. Now you can log in!');
}
```

Я ожидаю увидеть текст ошибки, но они просто не доходят до представления.

На этапе: *$request->validate($this->getValidationRules());* происходит переадресация на прошлую форму, но ошибки не выводятся. Xdebug помог понять, что request уходит с описанием ошибки, отловленной валидатором.

**Роутер**:

```
Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function() {
    Route::post('/createNewUser', 'createNewUser')->name('createNewUser');
    Route::post('/authenticate', 'authenticate')->name('authenticate');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'dashboard')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/register', 'register')->name('register');
    Route::get('/login', 'login')->name('login');
    Route::post('/updateUser', 'updateUser')->name('updateUser');
    Route::post('/logout', 'logout')->name('logout');
});
```

**Middleware:**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ...
```

имеет запись ShareErrorsFromSession для удержания ошибок форм.Кеш чистил, попытка уловить $errors или $session('errors') с помощью dd() и var_dump() ни к чему не привела.

Представление подключено корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить сделать так, создаете request:

> php artisan make:request UserCreateRequest

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class UserCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            //правила валидации
        ];
    }

    //формирует ответ, если валидация провалена
    //можете привести к тому, виду который вам нужен
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $errors = [];
        foreach($validator->errors()->getMessages() as $field => $error){
            $errors[$field] = $error[0];
        }

        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['errors' => $errors]));
    }
    
    
    //можете задать кастомные тексты ошибок
    public function messages(){
        return [
            'field1.required' => __('validation.required'),
            'field2.required' => __('validation.another_error')
        ];
    }
    
    //или переименовать атрибуты
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'field1' => 'Мыло, а не e-mail'
        ];
    }
}
```

А и используете его в контроллере:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;


...

public function createNewUser(UserCreateRequest $request): Response|RedirectResponse
{
    $photo = $this->handleProfilePhoto($request);
    $data = $this->prepareUserData($request, $photo);

    $user = new User();
    $user->create($data);
    $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success','Registering was successful. Now you can log in!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки не отображаются, скорее всего потому-что вы их не обрабатываете.

Обратитесь к документации Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors